Android app is mistakenly taken as instant
I have two product flavors "rstd" for standard app and "rprv" (preview) for instant app.
For instant app the manifest has
 <manifest ....
     android:targetSandboxVersion="2">
     
      <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
     
     ....

for standard app the manifest has neither of those.
Also I have
rprvImplementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:18.1.0"

in build.gradle.
Everything worked all right, but suddenly whatever Active Build Variant I select, it comes up with instant app, so the run log always has messages like
INFO - Pushing instant app to device...
INFO - Launching app...
INFO - Instant app started

In expectation that it make take the wrong manifest, I removed the lines related to instant app from 'rprv' manifest, removed the line for instant apps library, cleared the cache, rebuilt the project, but still cannot get rid of instant app.
Is there anything else apart from manifest lines and instant apps library indicating instant app?
